# Error when trying to use React useref in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Using React and typescript I am building a tabs component where you can scroll through tab links left to right at the top with overflow: scroll set. This works with a trackpad but I need to implement a method for mouse users so they can click and scroll much like in this codepen: https://codepen.io/thenutz/full/VwYeYEE
the code I have so far for the tab Links which sits above tab Content looks like this:

```html
<div className='container'>
  <div className='flex-row'
    sx={{ overflow: 'scroll',
    '::-webkit-scrollbar': { display: 'none' },
    display: flex,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'no-wrap' }}>
    <div className='tabLinks'
       sx={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'no-wrap'}}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => ( //LOOPS THROUGH TAB LINKS HERE ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The tabLinks div is the div that needs to be scrolled horizontally by both a trackpad and mouse(click and drag)

my first attempt at doing this was using react useRef to creat a ref for div with ClassName 'tabLinks'

```
const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
```

This ref was then passed to the tabLinks div and I tried to implement the onMouseDown events as per the codepen example but ran into this error below:

```
Property 'offsetLeft' does not exist on type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  let startX
  let scrollLeft

<div className='container'>
  <div className='flex-row'
    sx={{ overflow: 'scroll',
    '::-webkit-scrollbar': { display: 'none' },
    display: flex,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'no-wrap' }}>
        <div
          className='items'
          sx={{
            display: 'flex', 
            flexDirection: 'row',
            flexWrap: 'no-wrap'
           }}
          ref={ref}
          onMouseDown={e => {
            isDown= true
            const offset = ref.current?.offsetLeft || 0
            startX = e.pageX - offset
            scrollLeft = ref.current?.scrollLeft
          }}
          onMouseUp={e => {
            isDown = false;
          }}
          onMouseLeave={e => {
            isDown = false
          }}
          onMouseMove={e => {
            if(!isDown) return;
            e.preventDefault();
            const x = e.pageX - (ref.current?.offsetLeft ?? 0)
            const walk = (x - startX) * 3; //scroll-fast
            ref.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk
            console.log(walk)
          }}
        >
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => ( //LOOPS THROUGH TAB LINKS HERE ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I now am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property scrollLeft, object is not extensible
    at onMouseMove (index.tsx:102)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:270)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:561)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:583)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:680)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:688)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:662)
```

Comment: Try `ref.current.offsetLeft`

Comment: Using ref.current.offsetLeft results in an error:
 "object is possibly null"

Comment: Of course, it's initialized as null so you just need to check that it's not null.

Comment: ref.current?.offsetLeft

Comment: @cbr I am pretty new to typescript how would I go about that?

Comment: @Ibraheem this results in object is possibly 'undefined'

Comment: Either what Ibraheem said, or just `if (ref.current !== null)`

Comment: It would help if you post your code

Comment: @Ibraheem I have updated the code to reflect what I have tried so far. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

const offset = ref.current?.offsetLeft ?? 0;

And the same for:

scrollLeft = ref.current?.scrollLeft ?? 0;

This makes sure that both variables have a numeric value when the current ref is null.

You will need the null coalescing operator. If you don’t have that available then use:

const offset = ref.current?.offsetLeft || 0;
scrollLeft = ref.current?.scrollLeft || 0;

Comment: This has solved one issue I was facing. I have updated my original post to show all the code. This is how I a trying to achieve the scrolling by clicking and dragging. 
Any help?

Comment: You get the current ref value from `ref.current` not `ref`

Comment: where am I not doing that?

Comment: `ref.scrollLeft`